# CSS wild card for complex ID's

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

If I had a css selector such as `#subtab-1, #subtab-2 etc`

I could make the wildcard selector as such`div[id^='subtab-']`

But I cannot figure out how to make a wild card for selectors such as

```
#subtab-1-sub1 
#subtab-1-sub2 
#subtab-1-sub2 
#subtab-2-sub1 
#subtab2-sub2 
#subtab2-sub-3
etc...
```

How can you make something like:

```css
div[id^='subtab-*tab-*'] (*=wildcard)
```

Comment: You should edit the question and try to clarify. From your comment on Musa's answer, I'm guessing you are trying create a selector that will select all ids that fit something like the regular expression `subtab-[0-9]+-sub[0-9]+`? A sample of the current HTML structure would help, and also knowing if changing that structure is an option.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is coming from a back end that i didn't architect and cannot modify. One of those situations.Yes you are correct on the regex

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to select all elements whose id starts with `subtab-` followed by a number, followed by `-sub` followed by another number. It also sounds like you want this selector to not match `#subtab-1`, only things that have a suffix like `#subtab-1-sub1`.

This cannot be done with CSS. CSS does not supply a [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) that will allow wildcards. You can however hack something together that comes pretty close.

#### Hacky selector that might work

`[id^="subtab-"][id*="-sub"]` would match any id that starts with `subtab-` and also contains `-sub` somewhere in the id. This will probably work but could cause false positives on things like `#subtab-1-subtle` or `#subtab-something-sub2`, `#subtab-sub`, etc.

#### Another hacky selector that might work

Making the assumption that `#subtab-?-sub?` elements are always contained inside of `#subtab-?` elements and that `#subtab-?` elements can never contain another `#subtab-?` element, you could use the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) to target them: `[id^="subtab-"] > [id^="subtab-"]`

#### Relying on a class instead

A **better solution** would probably be to give all of the elements you are trying to target a common [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html), for instance `<div class="subtab-sub">`, then selecting them all would be as easy as `.subtab-sub`. Using a class would also yield much faster performance than using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Comment: After a little modification, this worked "div[id^="subtab-"] > [id^="tabs-"]" Thank you very much for the idea of a child selector w/wildcards. Very cool.

Answer (score 2):

All the ids start with `subtab` so use

```
div[id^='subtab']
```

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough, sorry! I don't want it to affect "#subtab-1" only "#subtab-WC-subWC" WC=WildCard, SO doesn't like "asterisks" in the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to use IDs constructed in this fashion as a way to address elements in your HTML. I'd experiment with using classes such as `subsubtab`, and you could try using the `nth-child` pseudo-class to individually address subtabs or subsubtabs:

```
<div class="tabs">
   <div class="subtab">
     <div class="subsubtab">...</div>
     <div class="subsubtab">...</div>
     ...
   </div>
   <div class="subtab">
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Then, your CSS would look like

```
div.subsubtab { color: brown; }
```

or

```
div.subtab:nth-child(2) { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Comment: Yeah its definitely not ideal, but is what I have to work with. Back end is held together w/ducttape and is legacy and will not be modified. Im tasked with making the pieces work.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look into this [jQuery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)

I think it can work.