# jQuery not working in WordPress dashboard option page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am trying to develop a WordPress theme with custom theme options. I have added a dashboard option page but jQuery inside that page isn't working. Here is what I did step by step.

Created a functions.php file with this code:

```
<?php
//wp_enqueue_script('jQuery UI Core');



add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_options_page' );

function register_options_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'merry_options', 'get_theme_options', 'dashicons-share-alt', 99 );
}

function get_theme_options()
{
 echo "<h1>MerryPress Theme Options</h2>Version: 1.0 Beta";

 $fullDirectoryPath=get_template_directory_uri()."/framework/themeoptions.php";
 //echo $fullDirectoryPath; 
 $optionsContent=file_get_contents($fullDirectoryPath);

 echo $optionsContent;
}

?>
```

In themeoptions.php, I added the jQuery Tab UI code. Here is what I have in that file:

```
<h1>Holla!</h1>
<?php 

    function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery ui core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' ); // wp_enqueue_scripts action hook to link only on the front-end

    echo "- end of php functions";
?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
  </script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not getting any error or warning in the dashboard. Just that the code doesn't run. Debugging is enabled. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: Here is the dashboard screenshot with developer console output:
[image]

Comment: Can you check the developer console to see if there are any errors? in chrome you can open developer console by pressing F12

Comment: @Ahmed When I remove the wp_enqueue_script code, the page gets fully loaded but I get these errors on the developer console:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function admin.php?page=merry_options:146
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined

That is I guess because jQuery was not found. Otherwise, no errors.

Comment: Replace $ with jQuery or try the snippet I have posted below.

Comment: So rather than using `$(document)..` use `jQuery(document)...` as Jai has suggested.

Comment: @Ahmed Tried that but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're missing `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );`.

But there are other issues. This is not ok *at all* <sup>(simplified)</sup>:

```
$path=get_template_directory_uri()."/file.php";
$content = file_get_contents( $path );
echo $content;
```

- `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', etc )` does not belong inside `file.php`
- it should be `admin_enqueue_scripts`

jQuery and jQuery UI core are encoded by default at admin side (check the browser dev tools Sources tab), but as said, not UI Tabs. See all included scripts: [Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress).
Full working code, check comments:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_options_page' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' ); 

function register_options_page()
{
    $my_hook = add_menu_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'merry_options', 'get_theme_options', 'dashicons-share-alt', 99 );
    // var_dump($my_hook); die();
}

function my_scripts_method( $hook ) 
{
    if( 'toplevel_page_merry_options' !== $hook ) // Previously at: var_dump + die
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
    # As best practice, the CSS AND JAVASCRIPT bellow should be enqueued here too
}

function get_theme_options()
{
    # Use THIS, not file_get_contents
    // include_once '/framework/themeoptions.php'; 
    ?>
    <h1>MerryPress Theme Options</h2>Version: 1.0 Beta
    <h1>Holla!</h1>
    <style> /* adjustments for testing */
    div[id^='tabs-']{ /* http://stackoverflow.com/a/16329932/1287812 */
        clear:both;
        padding-top: .5em;
    }
    #tabs ul li {
        float:left;
        margin-right: 2.5em;
        background: #ccc;
        padding:1em;
    }
    #tabs ul li.ui-tabs-active {
        background: #fff;
    }   
    </style>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
            <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
            <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script  type='text/javascript'>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
        $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
      });
      </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works well. I wish I could give this 10 vote ups.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$` safely as this causes some issues in wordpress, you can try this:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // use jQuery and pass the $ in the args
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
</script>
```

and this php part i am getting little confused, seems to me that may be your ui lib is loaded before the jQuery.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery ui core' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

if that is the case then you can swap the positions of enqueuing:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery ui core' );
}
```

other than this you can share if you get any error in console.

Comment: There is no error. I tried this but still doesn't work. I have added the output screenshot in the question.

Comment: @UmairKhanJadoon Wordpress already uses `jQuery and jQuery ui` so why are you putting it there? if you can check once more by using my js code but remove the php part of enqueing libraries.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Removed the enqueing libraries, now getting this error in the developer console:
'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function admin.php?page=merry_options:146
2
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined '

Comment: one more thing go to the console and type `$` and hit enter. what does it says? plz share.

Comment: hmm...interesting, because jQuery is not loaded so `$` is undefined. Now at this point i am really stumped that should not be undefined because wordpress uses jQuery at the dashboard screen.

Comment: I can see the jQuery being loaded when I view the source. Just can't see jquery-ui anywhere in the source. But, anyways, $ should work. I am stuck here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55394/discussion-between-umair-khan-jadoon-and-jai).

Answer (score 0):

`$` is not defined in wordpress, you can wrap the script in an anonymous function like this

```
<script>
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```