# JavaFx CSS wildcard

Tags: css, regex, javafx, css-selectors, wildcard

I am looking for a solution to style a range of multiple id selectors of unknown number :

```
#id1 , #id2, #id3...., #idx{
    /* css goes here  */
}
```

Where x if defined at run time.  
I found many solutions for styling `HTML` like : `div[id^='id']` 
( [all the ids start with "id"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16329932/3992939)) but I don't know if and how it can be applied to JavaFx.

I am aware of alternative approached like using [PseudoClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html).
 My question is specifically about using wildcard (`id*`) like or regex.

Comment: AFAIK JavaFX does not support this. Furthermore `PseudoClass` does not seem to be the right tool for this purpose. PseudoClasses are used to toggle a state on and of, but in this case it's "always on". You should use a style class instead...

Comment: Thanks for your comment @fabian. My use case is actually dynamic (state changes and style accordingly) . Nevertheless wildcard can be useful, if applicable.